# Adding buttons Telegram Bot C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot in C#, I need to add a button. Telegram.Bot library version 19.0.0
How can I make buttons like in the screenshot below?
[image]

I need to find out how to add such buttons, and I’ll write their processing myself

Answer (score 1):

Firstly install : Install-Package Telegram.Bot from nuget (if you not installed early )

Create on message event :
`botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;`

U can create such button using InlineKeyboardMarkup :

```
static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message.Text != null)
    {

        var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
        {
            new [] 
            {
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Edit Name"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Edit About")
            },
            new [] 
            {
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Edit Description"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Edit Description Picture")
            },
            new [] 
            {
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Edit Botpic"),
                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Edit Commands")
            }
        });

        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
            chatId: e.Message.Chat,
            text: "Choose an option:",
            replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Something I couldn’t figure out how to add a handler, when I click on this button in the chat, nothing happens

Comment: After adding event botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage; click double tabl vs studio automaticly will create handler for you , dont do

Comment: in the new version of the library there is no longer such a subscription to messages
botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;